# Can a company see where you've taken their mobile hot spot?

Tags: wifi

Can a company track where you've taken their company hot spot?

Comment: A lot is going to depend on the type of hot spot and what monitoring capabilities it has as well as the monitoring capabilities of the service provider.

Comment: What do mean with *taken* their hot spot? How can you take it *somewhere*? Please [edit] to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume they would be able to as long as the hotspot is on, they could call their provider of the hotspot and get them to trace it.